# Drawing elements (arrows & circle) in ggplot (R) to show the difference between two bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot in R using ggplot that shows the difference between my two bars in a nice way.

I found an example that did part of what I wanted, but I have two major problems:

1. It is based on comparing groups of bars, but I only have two, so I added one group with both of them.
2. I would like to draw the arrow in nicer shape. I attached an image.

Code:

```
transactions <- c(5000000, 1000000)
time <- c("Q1","Q2")
group <- c("A", "A")

data <- data.frame(transactions, time, group)

library(ggplot2)

fun.data <- function(x){
  print(x)
  return(data.frame(y = max(x) + 1,
                    label = paste0(round(diff(x), 2), "cm")))
}

ylab <- c(2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10)

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = transactions, fill = colors_hc[1], label = round(transactions, 0))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(group = group), position = position_nudge(0.1),
            arrow = arrow()) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = group, y = transactions),
               geom = "label",
               fun.data = fun.data,
               fontface = "bold", fill = "lightgrey",
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, NA), y = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = paste0(ylab, "M"),
                     breaks = 10 ^ 6 * ylab) 

gg
```

The arrows I am aiming for:

[image]

Where I am (ignore the ugliness, didn't style it yet):
[image]

Comment: take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145952/ggplot-how-to-connect-certain-bars-in-a-chart-with-arrows

Comment: That is actually the example I used and now I am not sure if it was the correct direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but you still need to play around a bit with the axes (or rather beautify them)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    
transactions <- c(5000000, 1000000)
time <- c("Q1","Q2")
group <- c("A", "A")

my_data <- data.frame(transactions, time, group)

fun.data <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y = max(x) + 1,
                    label = as.integer(diff(x))))
}

my_data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = group, y = transactions, fill = time)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label = as.integer(transactions)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = group), position = position_nudge(0.1),
            arrow = arrow()) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = group, y = transactions), 
               geom = "label",
               size = 5,
               position = position_nudge(0.05),
               fun.data = fun.data,
               fontface = "bold", fill = "lightgrey",
               inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Edit2:

```
y_limit <- 6000000
my_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = transactions)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           fill = 'steelblue') +
  geom_text(aes(label = as.integer(transactions)),
            vjust = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, y_limit)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 'Q1', y = max(my_data$transactions), 
                   xend = 'Q1', yend = y_limit)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 'Q2', y = y_limit, 
                   xend = 'Q2', yend = min(my_data$transactions)), 
               arrow = arrow()) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 'Q1', y = y_limit, 
                   xend = 'Q2', yend = y_limit)) +
  geom_label(aes(x = 'Q2', 
                 y = y_limit, 
                 label = as.integer(min(my_data$transactions)- max(my_data$transactions))),
             size = 10,
             position = position_nudge(-0.5),
             fontface = "bold", fill = "lightgrey")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to get the grouping thing away, because in my case it is not needed since I have only two bars. Basically time is x and transactions y.

Can you point me to how I would make the arrow more towards my "ideal" outcome? I am pretty unsure about how to draw several pieces and connect them.

Comment: Sure you can also hack that, however the code will not be pretty

Comment: adding a line (or rather arrow), is quite straight forward, specially if you are using ``geom_segment``, you basically have to tell the segment where to start and where to. If you need to do this often you might need to define new data frame of functions, however if this is a one time thing you can hard code the aesthetic needed for the segment, in fact I'll edit my code again with plot with hard coded segments

Comment: That is pretty cool and I think I got the logic. How does arrow_df look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's leftover from my trial and error, just remove it you don't need it. I got it out of the answer as well

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot, it is really helpful and with some smaller adjustments it works fine with my original data + I understand it better, than the original approach.